# where is open-ride.com's OpenRideServer.ear file located or generated?

Tags: glassfish

I have downloaded the opensource code at open-ride.com in order to set up a rideshare server and associated services.

I am trying to find the ".ear" file that they talk about in the install manual.

does it have to be generated somehow from the downloaded source code?

Answer (score 0):

It has to be generated either manually or through NetBeans. I haven't found out how to do it manually yet, but if you follow the NetBeans instructions you should be able to build it and run it. You might run into an error with the yui compressor where you just need to remove the ../ from the path to it in the configuration file. If you still have problems I may still be able to help.